# Parse and Query Large XML File Using Python

Tags: python, xml, data-mining

I am working on a project for which I have to parse and query a relatively large xml file in python. I am using a dataset with data about scientific articles. The dataset can be found via this link (https://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.xml.gz). There are 7 types of entries in the dataset: `article`, `inproceedings`, `proceedings`, `book`, `incollection`, `phdthesis` and `masterthesis`. An entry has the following attributes: `author`, `title`, `year` and either `journal` or `booktitle`.

I am looking for the best way to parse this and consequently perform queries on the dataset. Examples of queries that I would like to perform are:

- retrieve articles that have a certain author
- retrieve articles if the title contains a certain word
- retrieve articles to which author x and author y both contributed.
- ...

Herewith a snapshot of an entry in the xml file:

```
<article mdate="2020-06-25" key="tr/meltdown/s18" publtype="informal">
<author>Paul Kocher</author>
<author>Daniel Genkin</author>
<author>Daniel Gruss</author>
<author>Werner Haas 0004</author>
<author>Mike Hamburg</author>
<author>Moritz Lipp</author>
<author>Stefan Mangard</author>
<author>Thomas Prescher 0002</author>
<author>Michael Schwarz 0001</author>
<author>Yuval Yarom</author>
<title>Spectre Attacks: Exploiting Speculative Execution.</title>
<journal>meltdownattack.com</journal>
<year>2018</year>
<ee type="oa">https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf</ee>
</article>
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to do to this efficiently?

I have experimented with using the ElementTree. However, when parsing the file I get the following error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &Ouml;: line 90, column 17
```

Additionally, I am not sure if using the ElementTree will be the most efficient way for querying this xml file.

Comment: The best way of parsing huge xml files is with XmlReader which you can do in either c# or powershell.  Here is one of my answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700828/how-to-parse-large-6-gb-xml-file-in-python-and-save-some-of-the-elements-in-a

Comment: There are 3 section in the xml 1) Articles 2) www 3) inproceedings.  The first question is how do you want the output?  I would put data into a database which makes it easier to query.  I like using SQL Server.

Comment: Telling us it's "relatively large" is useless. That could be anything from 1Mb to 10Gb. If you can't give us a number, then it's not worth mentioning the size at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is large, and you want to perform multiple queries, then you don't want to be parsing the file and building a tree in memory every time you do a query. You also don't want to be writing the queries in low-level Python, you need a proper query language.

You should be loading the data into an XML database such as BaseX or ExistDB. You can then query it using XQuery. This will be a bit more effort to set up, but will make your life a lot easier in the long run.